# Where is the one dollar?

Tags: mathematics

Three men go to a restaurant. They order some food. After they have finished, they ask for the bill. The bill was **30$** . They pay the bill and leave the restaurant.

As soon as they leave, the manager find out that there was a miscalculation and that they actually had to pay **25$** .

He calls the waiter, give him the extra  **5\$**, and ask him to pass this money back to men. The waiter leaves the restaurant with **5\$** , but he put **2\$** in his pocket and give each man **1\$**.

So

Each man payed  $  10\$-1\$ = 9\$ $. 

Three man payed $ 9\$*3=27\$ $.

The waiter has $ 2\$ $

The total is $ 27\$ + 2\$ = 29\$ $

Where is the last  $ 1\$ $?

Comment: Please solve this: I am new in this site... I knew a puzzle, I've **searched** the site to find if the puzzle is there or not.. I couldn't find it, (as you might guess a puzzle can be asked in many different ways) . I put a new post... I get 4 down votes. Why do I get down votes ?  Isn't  *a marked as duplicate* enough ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's represent restaurant manager by **R**, men by **M** and waiter by **W**.

> Since money can neither be created nor be destroyed (unless government is involved).

We can represent it by a simple mathematical equation :

> Money(**R**) + Money(**M**) + Money(**W**) = 0

For manager,

> Money(**R**) = 30\$ - 5\$ = 25\$

For mens,

> Money(**M**) = -30\$ + 3\$ = -27$

For waiter,

> Money(**W**) = 2\$

summing them up

> 25 - 27 + 2 = 0.

And explanation to why your calculation was wrong:

> 27 should be represented with a negative sign, since that was a loss (from calculation perspective). And the 2 should be positive as it was gain.

Comment: ...It's a restaurant. :P

Comment: @Mithrandir Done..:D

Comment: Haha, law of conservation of money ^-^

Comment: @ABcDexter I know :D.. while writing the answer this struck me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic puzzle. The answer is

> They gave \$30. The waiter keeps 2 and gives 3 back. Everyone gets one dollar. \$25 + \$2 + \$3 = \$30. No missing money.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, they payed 27$, 25$ to the restaurant and 2$ to the waiter.